# Python HeapPushPop not popping minimum element

Tags: python, sorting, heap

I feel like I must be misunderstanding heappushpop because I can't make  out why this is happening.

```
sequence = [2, 6, 4, 5, 8]
result = []
x = [3, -1]
result.append(heapq.heappushpop(x, sequence[0]))
```

Should this not push 2 onto the heap x and pop -1? I'm getting the 2 pushed and popped.

Comment: `x` is not a heap and is not in the correct order, you'd need to call `heapq.heapify(x)` first before expecting `x` to behave as a heap correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you didn't work with a min heap to start with.

`x` is *not* a min heap. You cannot expect a `heapq` function that works on a heap to give a sensible result when the list you pass to it is not a heap.

So first do:

```
heapq.heapify(x)
```

Test:

```
import heapq

x = [3, -1]
heapq.heapify(x)
print(heapq.heappushpop(x, 2))  # outputs -1
print(x)  # outputs [2, 3]
```